# Java - How to define a variable with variable type

Tags: java, android, class, oop, variables

I have to declare a variable, the type of this variable depends on a parameter, so I have an *if* clause and define this variable there:

```
if(this.httpMethod == "POST"){
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
}
if(this.httpMethod == "GET"){
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
}
```

The problem is that in Java, the scope of that variable lies inside the *if*, so I can't use it later !. If I try:

```
request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

That gives me:  *request cannot be resolved*

So, the **question** would be: how can I define a variable, that it's type depends on a parameter.

**What I have tried**:

- Setting the variable to *final*.

**My current solution** is to duplicate the code, inside every *if* clause, I set the same
Headers, Connection, grab the response,  .... So, of course, I don't like this.

**Design**. I have this HTTP request class like this, so I can use it to handle the request, so, I just have to send it some parameters (URL, method, authentication, ...) , and it will give me back the result. This class is my bottom layer of my Android app, that looks like this:

1. *Activities.java* (all the activities)
2. *Core.java* (handle resources)
3. *HttpRequest.java* (handle internet resources)

Comment: `if(this.httpMethod.equals("POST"))`. use .equals to compare strigns

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks for remind me that. I will change it. Although my question still open...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `HttpPost` and `HttpGet` inherit `HttpRequestBase`. So you can declare the request variable outside the `if` statement like so:

```
HttpRequestBase request = null;

if (this.httpMethod.equals("POST")) {
   request = new HttpPost(url);
}
else if (this.httpMethod.equals("GET")) {
   request = new HttpGet(url);
}

request.addHeader(...); etc
```

Comment: I just tested this. Works perfect. Thanks for the explanation also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable to be of the supertype outside of the `if` blocks and then use it inside them:

```
        HttpRequestBase request = null;

        if("POST".equals(this.httpMethod)){
            request = new HttpPost(url);
        }
        else if("GET".equals(this.httpMethod)){
            request = new HttpGet(url);
        }
```

And then later in your code when you're ready to use it, be sure to check whether the request is `null` or not.

*Edited based on changes to the original question*

Comment: I can't, Java won't let me change the type of a variable.

Comment: This sidesteps the important issue, though, because in the code you're skipping the difference between the two methods.

Comment: I just realized you had a typo in your posted code and were setting two different subtypes.

Comment: I edited my question. Yes, that answer work. Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23743896/2615737

Comment: Edited my answer to be correct as well. Please note that the `"GET".equals(this.httpMethod)` style will not throw a `NullPointerException` if `httpMethod` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a variable of both variable types' superclass outside the if statements.  Example:

```
Superclass object;

if (condition){
    object = new Subclass1();
}
else {
    object = new Subclass2();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think you meant like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23743896/2615737